# Jasmine react component, test keeps failing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a jasmine test for my react component, I would like to test the select all checkbox unchecks when the publish event is fired from one of the checked checkboxs. As not all all of the checkboxes will then be checked, so the select all needs to uncheck. Below is my jasmine test and component, I'm new to testing react components anyhelp much appreciated:

**Currently get error, undefined is not an object this.stubs.subscribe**

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var postal = require('postal');
var contactChannel = postal.channel("contact")
var SelectAll = require('../../../components/controls/SelectAll');
var channelStub = require('../../stub/channelStub');

// When subscribe event check checkbox

describe("Select All Checkbox Specification", function() {

describe("Checking deselect response", function () {

it("On receive subscribe event uncheck the select all box", function () {

        // when the select all is created it will create the channel
        // publish an event to the channel (de-select event)

        instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<SelectAll />);

        // publish event to check all checkboxes
        contactChannel.publish({
            channel: 'contact',
            topic: 'selectAll',
            data: {
                selectAll: true
            }});

        var checkbox = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(instance, "input");

        // publish event to uncheck select all checkbox
        contactChannel.publish({
            channel: "basket",
            topic: "deselectedContact",
            data: {}
        });

        // Checking the module - to see if the checkbox inside is unchecked

        var checkbox = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(instance, "input");

        var data = this.stubbed.subscribe();
        // check box checked should be false
        expect(data.topic === 'deselectedContact');
        expect(input.checked === false);
    });
```

React component:

```
var postal = require('postal');var postal = require('postal');
var contactChannel = postal.channel("contact");
var React = require('react');

var SelectAll = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        checked:false
    };
},

setUnChecked: function(){
    this.setState({checked: false});
},

handler: function(e) {

    var updatedContacts = [],
        contacts = this.props.data.contacts,
        topic = 'selectAll',
        checked = false,
        channel = 'contact';

    contactChannel.publish({
        channel: channel,
        topic: topic,
        data: {
            selectAll: event.target.checked
        }});

        this.setState({checked: event.target.checked});
},

render: function() {

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked}
                onChange={this.handler} ref="checkAll" />
        </div>
    );
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    contactChannel.subscribe("deselectedContact", function(data) {
        self.setUnChecked();
    });
}

});

module.exports = SelectAll;
```

ChannelStub:

```
var lastPublished = {},
lastTopicSubscribed = '',
lastCallbackSubscribed;

var ChannelStub = {

publish: function(data) {
    lastPublished = data;
},

getLastPublished: function() {

    return lastPublished;
},

subscribe: function(topic, callback) {

    lastCallbackSubscribed = callback;
    lastTopicSubscribed = topic;
}



};

module.exports = ChannelStub;
```

Comment: What’s `this.stubbed`? Where does it come from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited my post to include the stub

Comment: You still never defined `this.stubbed` in your test.